# HTML coding for active menu color customization

Tags: html, colors

I am trying to change the color of the active category/page.

I don't want to modify files and anyway, I can't, so I am trying to change it through:

> Appearance > Menus

Putting the HTML code into the Navigation Label of the page I want to customize.

I found one code and it seems to work properly:

```
<span style=”color: #a57a6b;”>Home</span>
```

But this code changes the color at all.

How could I transform it to work only while in the active module?

Answer (score 0):

HTML by itself has static properties.

Changing the color must change the **color:** parameter in the HTML language itself. Do you want to consider using additional languages like **CSS**?

If you only rely on full HTML, color change can be done by redirecting a different page with the same data and a different **color:** attribute.

Comment: I tried everything involving CSS, but it doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Run in Browser [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console)

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span')).filter(function (el) {return el.textContent === 'Home'})[0].style.color = "blue";
```

Where `...color = "blue"` is color what you want